# Domain name not resolving to custom nameservers

Tags: azure, nameserver, dns-zone, dns-hosting, plesk

I set up a linux VM on azure running centos 7 and installed plesk obsidian. I configured the DNS settings there and was told to first update the glue records on namecheap, then set the nameservers to my custom nameservers: ns1.domain.name and ns2.domain.name. I have done all that yet it fails to resolve the domain name. I have waited for more than 24 hours yet still the same.

Attached are the screenshots of the settings on namecheap and on plesk.

Please would appreciate any prompt help I can get. Thank you.

[namecheap glue record preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0OXR.png)
[namecheap nameserver setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyCJf.png)
[plesk dns settings preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csKMx.png)

Comment: The glue records must point to a public IP - how else would someone be able to query your server!?

Comment: Please elaborate @Virsacer. I’m a newbie

Comment: Simplified: When typing `www.example.com` in your browser, DNS tries to find out who is responisble for `*.com` and recieves an IP, then it tries to find out who is responsible for `*.example.com` and recieves the name `ns1.example.com`. At this point the glue is neccessary since it can not ask `ns1` what its IP is. The glue points to `10.1.1.4`. But this is a private IP, so it cannot reach it to query anything for `example.com`.

Comment: Also: For redundancy `ns1` and `ns2` should be two different machines.

Comment: I'm still confused @Virsacer. Please just tell me exactly what to do or just point me in the right direction. Thank you. Are you saying I should use the public IP for the glue record instead? What of the DNS settings on plesk?

Comment: If you want anything to be reachable, you have to use the public IP everywhere...